# Python error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, gaussian

I'm going to do 2D Gaussian fit in Python 3 by:

```
def gaussian_fit_2_d(data, amplitude, x0, y0, sigma_x, sigma_y, theta, offset):

    x0 = np.float64(x0)
    y0 = np.float64(y0)

    a = (np.cos(theta) ** 2) / (2 * sigma_x ** 2) + (np.sin(theta) ** 2) / (2 * sigma_y ** 2)
    b = -np.sin(2 * theta) / (4 * sigma_x ** 2) + np.sin(2 * theta) / (4 * sigma_y ** 2)
    c = (np.sin(theta) ** 2) / (2 * sigma_x ** 2) + (np.cos(theta) ** 2) / (2 * sigma_y ** 2)
    x = data["x"]
    y = data["y"]
    f = offset + amplitude * np.exp(-((a * (x - x0)) ** 2 + 2 * b * (x - x0) * (y - y0) + c * (y - y0) ** 2))
    return f.ravel()

image = sio.loadmat("File Name")
intensity = np.float64(np. array(image["p1"]))
data_size = intensity.shape

x = np.arange(0, data_size[1])
y = np.arange(0, data_size[0])
# print(data_size)
# print(x)

[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(x, y)
data = {"x": X, "y": Y}

popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(gaussian_fit_2_d, data, intensity)
```

,but in the last line I got the following error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
>   (1558,) (41,38)

any idea?

Comment: the shape of 2 ndarrays does not fit together. Find the (41,38) shape array and append a `.flatten()`. Should work then

Comment: @MarkusDutschke actually, the `intensity` has (41,38) shape. Should I apply that before passing to `curve_fit`?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise curve_fit does not know what element to realate to what. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: @MarkusDutschke    Now , I don't get the error. it returns the optimized parameters,  but the Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated. and it returns an array of `inf`

Comment: This is a mathematical issue originating from your data now. You can try to play around with the parameters p0, bounds and method for your fit. The easiest is to play around with the example in the scipy documentation, which I linked before